# $f, 1/f$ integrable implies that $f^2$, $1/f^2$ integrable?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, borel-measures

on the measure space $(X,A,m)$ let $f: X \to \mathbb R$ be Borel-measurable, it is given that $f$, $1/f$ are well-defined and integrable.

I would like to prove that this implies that $f^2$ and $1/f^2$ are integrable but am stuck on this part. I thought about using Hölder's inequality, do you guys have any hints?

Comment: MathJax is required for questions

Comment: Why do you suspect your statement is true?

Comment: I would actually like to prove that this implies that m(X) is finite. So I defined h:= ƒ*(1/ƒ) = 1. If I take the Lebesgue integral of h, I get m(X). If h is integrable, then m(X) is finite. I thought if I show that $f^2$, 1/$f^2$ is integrable, by Hölder's inequality this would imply that ƒ*1/ƒ = h = 1 is integrable

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{x}$ and $1/\sqrt{x}$ are integrable on $(0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, but $1/x$ is not.

Comment: yes but 1/x is not well-defined in 0, in my case f and 1/f are well-defined

Comment: $0$ is not part of the measure space; we don't need to define it there.

Comment: @mathsisrad Robert excluded zero from the domain, but even if you don't, you can arbitrarily define $f$ at $0$ and the problem persists. It's not clear to me what notion you're trying to iron out with "well-defined"; you might be assuming that they are both $L^\infty$ but then the result is trivial.

Comment: hmm but would the given criteria imply that f is in L^p, 1/f is in L^q with 1/p + 1/q = 1? All I want to show is that I can use Hölder's inequality to prove that f*(1/f) = 1 is integrable

Comment: Hint: If $f$ and $g$ are integrable, so is $\sqrt{|f g|}$.

Comment: thank you so much!!! I think I got it now!

Comment: @mathsisrad I just want to point out that what you just experienced is a well-known thing called an XY problem: you want to do X, but you think the best way to do X is to do Y, so you pose your question as "how can I do Y?" without presenting X at all. Then it turns out that Y is actually not the best way to do X (or maybe Y is just impossible), so some time was wasted in the process of figuring out what X was. Generally the way to avoid XY problems is to pose the "X" problem you actually want to achieve and then propose "Y" as a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might prefer trying to prove something true.

Consider $\bigl((0,1), \mathcal B((0,1)), \mathcal L^1\bigr)$ and $f(x)=\sqrt x$.
Then $f$ and $1/f$ are integrable, but $1/f^2$ is not.